# The method has to be thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, completable-future

I had to transform a request from synchronous to async. It's something like

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> <name> (<args>) {
<do something>
<do something very time consuming>
<return response>
}
```

So I had to return the response faster, and the "do something very time consuming" was blocking that, and I thought I would just run it in the background. I moved the code to a separate class and used CompletableFeatures to do that.

Now I have instead of "do something very time consuming" something like:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> <name> (<args>) {
<do something>

CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
   new <NewClass>.<NewMethod>(<args>);
});

<return response>
}
```

new NewClass.NewMethod(args); contains the time consuming code.

Seems like it works fine, but I want to know if I have to make sure the new code needs to be thread-safe? Any opinions here? Sorry for using fake names, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? There are multiple threads involved, whether or not you execute that code asynchronously: web servers handle multiple requests concurrently. So your code needs to take that into account no matter what.

Comment: I think what @JBNizet is saying is that the second approach has the same thread safety requirements as the first, right?

Comment: Ok, so a rest endpoint implementation has to be always thread-safe? Sorry if I'm not coherent, still trying to understand the concepts.

Comment: To my knowledge, you only really need to worry about thread safety if you are modifying or accessing class variables.

Comment: For example, I use in that method ZipOutputStream to create a custom zip, and in JavaDoc says explicitly it's not thread-safe. I won't have to worry about that in this context? I initialize it withing the method invoked in CompletableFuture.runAsync((). So it's not a class variable, it's always a new initialized object.

Comment: thread-safety is all about mutable state shared between threads. Your ZipOutputStream is (hopefully) just a local variable in a method, and is thus never shared between threads, so it's safe, whether or not you execute your method asynchronously.

Comment: And yes, a rest endpoint implementation has to be always thread-safe

Comment: Thanks a lot, JB Nizet. This answer my question perfectly (your last two comments).

Answer (score -2):

In case you need to have the future task synchronized, you can simple add the synchronized key work on the future related method, for example:

```
public class SafeFuture {

    public void doWorkSynced() {
        System.out.println("doing something quick starting");
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::doWorkInBackground);
        System.out.println("doing something quick done");
    }

    private synchronized void doWorkInBackground() {
        try {
            System.out.println("doing something slower starting");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("doing something slower done");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SafeFuture safeFuture = new SafeFuture();
        safeFuture.doWorkSynced();
        safeFuture.doWorkSynced();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
doing something quick starting
doing something quick done
doing something quick starting
doing something quick done
doing something slower starting
doing something slower done
doing something slower starting
doing something slower done
```

As you can see, the time consuming task is not running is parallel

Comment: Chucking `synchronized` on things is a very blunt (and not necessarily effective) way to attempt to make them thread safe.

Comment: I need it to be multi-threaded, it's a download function, I need to build the zip in a specific way and have some time-consuming checks to do. I have to do it this way to not block the UI, but I can't synchronize the whole logic, it will take too much to download if many users decide to use the download at approximate times. But thank you all for the effort and responses.